# Codeigniter 2.1 - image name is not working properly on upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using this function to upload images, and it is working except in one part. Where there are more then one image for upload, all images get their name from the first image (overwrite is set to off, so CI is adding number at the end of the name). How can I solve this problem?

```
function img_upload($folder) {
    $this->path = './public/img/' . $folder;
    $imgs = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($_FILES as $key => $value):
        $img_name = is_array($value['name']) ? $value['name'][$count] : $value['name'];
        $img_name = $this->char_replace($img_name, '_');
        $count++;
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'upload_path' => $this->path,
            'file_name' => $img_name
        );
        $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($key != 'logo'):
            if (!$this->CI->upload->do_upload($key)) {
            } else {
                $image = $this->CI->upload->data();
                $imgs[] = $image['file_name'];
            }
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if(empty($imgs)):
        return FALSE;
    else:
        return implode(',', $imgs);
    endif;
}
```

Function **char_replace** is working without a problem.

```
function char_replace($text, $rep_simbol = " ")
{
    $char = array('!', '&', '?', '/', '/\/', ':', ';', '#', '<', '>', '=', '^', '@', '~', '`', '[', ']', '{', '}');
    return $name = str_replace($char, $rep_simbol, $text);
}
```

Comment: Please don't mix using the `if(): endif;` syntax with the `if(){}` syntax!

Comment: @RocketHazmat I didn't see that. I was changing this function, and some of the old code stayed. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Your `$count` variable is only getting incremented each time the `foreach` runs.  You want an inner loop to loop over the multiple files.

Comment: This is happening because of how `$this->CI->upload->do_upload` works.  It expects `$_FILES['key']` to only have one file, not an array of files. For my own program, I had this same issue, and I used a silly workaround to fix it.  I backed up the real `$_FILES` array, looped through that copy, then re-set the `$_FILES` array each time, so that `$this->CI->upload->do_upload` would read it as one file.

Comment: Can you show me your way code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->CI->upload->do_upload($key)` expects `$_FILES['key']` to only contain one file.

What you can do is, make a copy of `$_FILES`, loop through it, and for each file set the values of `$_FILES['key']`.

```
function img_upload($folder) {
    $this->path = './public/img/' . $folder;
    $imgs = array();

    // Copy of $_FILES
    $thisFiles = $_FILES;

    // Loop through copy of $_FILES
    foreach($theFiles as $key => &$value){
        // Create the $_FILES array for each individual file,
        // so that do_upload can read it correctly
        if(!is_array($value['name'])){
            // If it's not an array, make it one,
            // this will make our future code easier
            foreach($value as $kv => &$val){
                $val = array($val);
            }
        }

        // Loop through each file and upload each one
        foreach($value['name'] as $count=>$img_name){
            $img_name = $this->char_replace($img_name, '_');

            foreach($_FILES[$key] as $k => &$v){
                // CodeIgniter will think this is the $_FILES array
                $v = $theFiles[$key][$k][$count];
            }

            $config = array(
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
                'upload_path' => $this->path,
                'file_name' => $img_name
            );

            $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
            $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($key != 'logo'){
                if (!$this->CI->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                }
                else {
                    $image = $this->CI->upload->data();
                    $imgs[] = $image['file_name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return !empty($imgs) ? implode(',', $imgs) : FALSE;
}
```

<sub>NOTE: This is *untested*.</sub>

Comment: It needs a few tweaks, but I see the general idea. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Like I said, it's untested.  That's basically what you need to do, as `$this->CI->upload->do_upload($key)` assumes `$_FILES['key']` only has one file.